# When opening eclipse error message comming unsupported content type

Tags: eclipse

When I opening eclipse (Europa) it loads last opened files.

I have opened one jrxml file and when eclipse opening focused to jrxml file. So 
I need to remove opened files to avoid loading the jrxml tab when eclipse loading.

> Where eclipse stores opened tabls?

[image]
*Thanks*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some researches I found where eclipse stores workbench stat.

> (Workspace path)\.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workbench.xml